# set tinymce active editor with jquery but link is become different

Tags: ajax, load, tinymce

hi i am using tinymce and trying to load dynamic text to active editor by ajax but i have problem

here is my code

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "post",
  cache:false,
      url: "/sistem/plugins/etiketlink/form/index.php",          
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
    alert(data);             
            // tinymce.editors[0].setContent(data);
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);

      },
      error: function() {
         alert("error!");
      }
```

when i alert data my link are like `<a href="/didim.html" alt="didim" />`
but when `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);` works links are becoming like
 `<a href="../didim.html"`  so how can i delete this (..)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    convert_urls: false
});
```

Hope this helps!!